# Duda de JavaScript a Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nav

Estoy aprendiendo Jquery y quería pasar un codigo que ya tengo hecho en JavaScript y funciona perfecto a código Jquery para practicar y para dejar un código más limpio y fácil de mantener. 
Me estoy encontrando con un problema. No entiendo que estoy poniendo mal. A ver si me pueden ayudar. 
Este es mi codigo JavaScript que funciona perfecto.

```
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".cerrar-nav");
const openButton = document.querySelector(".abrir-nav");
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav");

closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.remove("nav-abierta");
});

openButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  nav.classList.add("nav-abierta");
});
```

Es una simple barra que de navegador que se despliega. 
Ahora les adjunto como lo escribí en Jquery a ver si me pueden decir que hice mal.

```
const cerrarBtn = $(".cerrar-nav");
const abrirBtn = $(".abrir-nav");
const nav = $(".nav");

cerrarBtn.on("click", quitarClase);

function quitarClase() {
  nav.removeClass(".nav-abierta");
}

abrirBtn.on("click", sumarClase);

function sumarClase() {
  nav.addClass(".nav-abierta");
}
```

Como veran lo unico que hice fue cambiar los selectores de DOM de JS por los selectores de Jquery y luego crear las mismas funciones pero con Jquery.

Comment: primero que nada, pregunta obvia, pero estas incluyendo en tu codigo el cdn de jquery? y por otro lado, cuando llamas a la funcion ``cerrarBtn.on("click", quitarClase);`` no deberias usar ``cerrarBtn.on("click", quitarClase())`` (poner parentesis al final del nombre de la funcion, para que el codigo entienda que se trata de ella

Comment: quise cerrar con un signo de pregunta y ya no me deja editarlo. Quise decir "no deberias usar parentesis al finalizar una funcion??" -> Desconozco si se pueden llamar funciones en js omitiendo el () al final de la funcion, por eso digo que tal vez tu error venga por ese lado.

Comment: @Mani el CDN de jquery esta funcionando. Ya lo he testeado. Lo de la función he probado de ambas formas e igualmente no funciona

Comment: bien, no se bien que puede estar pasando, pero estoy googleando y no puedo encontrar, si se puede llamar una funcion y declararla mas abajo. Si primero pones la funcion, y abajo de esta realizas la llamada, el error persiste??

Comment: Sería bueno que pasaras el HTML.

Comment: Esto es algo subjetivo, pero si te das cuenta ambos trozos de código son igual de largos, mantenibles y elegantes. Aunque JQuery sigue siendo tremendamente popular, no es necesario hoy día para crear código mantenible y compatible con todos los navegadores, el motivo por el que se creó JQuery ya no existe (no pelearte con distintos navegadores, especialmente con IE desde el 6 hasta el 10). Está bien conocer distintas librerías y frameworks, pero el no siempre es necesario usar uno+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código no funciona porque estás poniendo el punto en el `removeClass`, debes poner solamente la clase que quieres remover.

Quizá estás confundiendo [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), que es una función, con los [selectores](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/). En jQuery el selector de clase es `.nombre-Clase`, pero las funciones como `removeClass` deben recibir en parámetro el nombre de la clase (sin el punto), como bien explica la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

```js
const cerrarBtn = $(".cerrar-nav"); 
cerrarBtn.on("click", quitarClase); 
const nav = $(".nav");              


function quitarClase() {
  nav.removeClass("nav-abierta"); 
  console.log(1);
  console.log(nav.prop("classList"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav cerrar-nav nav-abierta">Click Aquí</nav>
```

Aunque el código anterior migrado realmente a jQuery, se vería así:

```js
const nav = $(".nav");

$(".cerrar-nav").on('click', function(event) {
  console.log(1);
  nav.removeClass( 'nav-abierta' );
  console.log(nav.prop("classList"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="nav-1" class="nav cerrar-nav nav-abierta">Click Aquí: Nav 1</nav>

<nav id="nav-2" class="nav cerrar-nav">Click Aquí: Nav 2</nav>
<nav id="nav-2" class="nav cerrar-nav nav-abierta">Click Aquí: Nav 3</nav>
```